# Passing data from instantiation to Vue component

Tags: vue.js

Let's say that I have a Vue Component:

```
<item v-bind:orangeFruit ></item>
```

and I want to pass in some computed properties from my Vue instantiation:

```
var fruits = {
  fruit1:'apple',
  fruit2:'orange',
  fruit3:'strawberry'
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    return fruits
  },
  computed: {
    orangeFruit: function(){
      // Assume this is much more complicated than just fetching a key
      return this.fruit2;
    }
  }

})
```

So then I'd do something like:

```
Vue.component('item,
   template:`

     // This should fetch the computed property from instantiation
     <p>{{ orangeFruit }}</p> `,

   props: {
     orangeFruit
   }
)
```

But this keeps returning an `orangeFruit undefined` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<item v-bind:orangeFruit ></item>
```

Should be:

```
<item :orangeFruit="orangeFruit"></item>
```

Your code should look like this:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    fruits : fruits 
  },
  computed: {
    orangeFruit: function(){
      // Assume this is much more complicated than just fetching a key
      return this.fruits.fruit2;
    }
  }

})
```

Comment: That makes sense to me. Thanks for the answer :)